# Finding maximum of a list of lists by sum of elements in Python

Tags: python, list, haskell, higher-order-functions

What's the idiomatic way to do [maximumBy](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Data-Foldable.html#v:maximumBy) (higher order function taking a comparison function for the test), on a list of lists, where the comparison we want to make is the sum of the list, in Python?

Here's a Haskell implementation and example output:

```
> maximumBy (compare `on` sum) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,3,5]]
> [4,5,6]
```

And implementations of those base library functions, just for completeness (in case you want to use reduce or something :)

```
maximumBy cmp xs =  foldl1 maxBy xs
    where
       maxBy x y = case cmp x y of GT -> x; _ -> y

k `on` f = \x y -> f x `k` f y

sum      =  foldl' (+) 0
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Since Python 2.5 you can use [max](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max) with a key parameter:

```
>>> max(a, key=sum)
[4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: max(a) seems to do the same thing.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy: The default behaviour is a lexicographical ordering which by chance happens to give the same result for this input data, but in general can give a different answer.

Comment: how can you now find the index of this max sublist. in the case above it would be 2

Answer (score 1):

It isn't terribly efficient, but:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x if sum(x)>sum(y) else y, [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,3,5]])
```

Comment: Comparing this with @Mark's correct answer is a delightful way to show why Python programmers would be by far best off _forgetting_ about `reduce` (good thing it's not a built-in any more in Py3!-).

Comment: @Alex: If someone had posted an answer using a for-loop, which would have also been much clumsier than Mark's answer, would you have argued that python programmers are better off forgetting about for-loops?

Comment: @sepp2k: `for` loops are a delightful way of showing why Python programmers should use list comprehensions. In all seriousness, there isn't always a replacement for a `for` loop, but that's usually not the case for `reduce`. As much as I personally like the `map`/`filter`/`reduce` trinity, Alex is right in that there usually is a better way.

Comment: @outis, I would say "there usually is a better way _in Python_" -- I wouldn't say it without the qualification since it may not be the case in, e.g., Haskell or Lisp.  But, we do agree on the gist;-).

Comment: You can only eliminate the `reduce` in this case because `max` is itself essentially `reduce` hard-coded to use the binary `max` function. This does nothing whatsoever to demonstrate that `reduce` isn't useful in the general case. It just demonstrates that if, for your particular case, there is a specialised function, you should use it.

Comment: @Alex: indeed, that is what I meant (since we're dealing w/ Python). If we were discussing Common Lisp...

Answer (score 1):

If max didn't have the key parameter you could code the DSU pattern explicitly:

```
max(izip(imap(sum,a),a))[1]
```

`izip` and `imap` are from the itertools module in python 2 and do what zip and map do, but lazily using Python generators, to avoid consing an intermediate list.  In Python 3, the map and zip builtins are lazy.